# How do I access to color of '+' add button in searchbar of MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I access to color of '+' add button in searchbar of MFMessageComposeViewController

I want to change color from blue to custom color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allowed to customize the MFMessageComposeViewController class.

Check the Apple Documentation for [MFMessageComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/index.html)